# API request/response codes when site is in read-only maintenance mode?

Tags: rest-api, httpresponse, read-only

I checked out [Read-Only Mode Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Read-Only-Mode-Overview&type=1&language=en_US) but I'm still unsure of how our API will respond, particularly the response code. Will POST/PUT requests automatically return a 503 service unavailable or will the Apex execute and try to issue DML statements and then fail with *INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE_NOT_ALLOWED_DURING_MAINTENANCE/InvalidReadOnlyUserDmlException*?

Ideally, I'd like to give our client a heads up what to expect.

Comment: I think it probably depends on the endpoint... If it's custom rest, I would expect the `InvalidReadOnlyUserDmlException` would happened when you execute your APEX DML.  The error code would be determined by your error handling of the exception.

If it's the standard rest API then you'll get the `INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE_NOT_ALLOWED_DURING_MAINTENANCE` error, but not sure what the Error code will be